# Rename "widows" tag to "latex-widows" or "tex-widows"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Recently I've come across the [widows](/questions/tagged/widows) tag on SO and found out that it was misused in 8 out of 9 questions (it was apparently mistaken for [windows](/questions/tagged/windows)). After fixing the mistakes, I thought it would be better to rename the confusing tag to something that might draw the attention more easily, and to make the old tag a synonym of the new one.

I have since retagged the [only question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386828/dealing-with-widows-in-a-multicol-environment) that seems to have used the tag legitimately to [latex-widows](/questions/tagged/latex-widows).

I'm now facing two issues:

1. I'm not entirely sure about the new name I chose. Should it be [tex-widows](/questions/tagged/tex-widows) instead?
2. I can't suggest a synonym as I have no reputation relevant to the area.

Comment: If the old tag is made a synonym for the new tag, the problem will persist. The old tag needs to be burninated.

Comment: The problem might persist, but perhaps to a lesser extent. When typing `widows`, the user would see only `latex-widows` as a suggestion, which, if irrelevant to the question, would probably make them review what they had typed. If not at that point then it might work later, after submitting the question: the originally typed `widows` would turn into `latex-widows`, which, again, would be more likely to catch their attention than just `widows`. Also, if burninating a tag means prohibiting its use, I don't think it would be a good idea. LaTeX users/developers might rightly be expected to use it.

Comment: Good point, well made! :-)